# Changing the color of bootstrap button text and symbol

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this certain code i would like to know how to change the color of the text from on the button blue to black. Not the color of the buttons background but the actual text that says dropdown along with the symbol. It is by default blue at the moment.

Site for reference and a live example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/ Code: The section the code is under is called "Using Drop downs" Tabs with drop downs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  ...
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: That's because the color of the links in bootstrap are that color. Use CSS to target that .nav-tabs > li > a { your style here
} or go to Customizer on their site and change the @brand-primary variable.

Comment: `.dropdown a{
    color: #000 !important;
}`

try this in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.dropdown-toggle{
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Is their anything else i could possible try?

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?
It seems to work here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51mefx64/)